# String contains no format specifiers

Tags: java, string

sonarlint reported me the error "String contains no format specifiers". What do I have to pay attention to when creating such a format? Below is an example where there is a mistake and a question for you what should I correct.

```
String.format("attachment; filename=\"\".xml", calendar.getICal()));
```

Comment: It's a bug: `String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\".xml", calendar.getICal()));` Original code would give `"".xml"`. Thanks, sonarlint.

Comment: what's the `String` type from? Depending on the language the format specifiers look differently. For C# for example it would be `String.format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\".xml", calendar.getICal()));`

Comment: @PeterT I corrected the tag, must be java.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this is right ?

```java
String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\".xml", 1);
```